# Extra Space showing above the Toolbar for Fragments. How to remove extra space above toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I tried to load fragments in activity. But there is more space above the toolbar?

Here I given what I tried in my app. Without fragment activity opens fine

Styles:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

activity_home.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".home.HomeActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: what is `PopupOverlay` ??

Comment: Its popup theme by default it defined in android for basic activity

Comment: and what is the need to set popUpTheme to `Toolbar` ??

Comment: put no action bar theme for your activity in menifest file..

Comment: Then put it in **manifest**  not in **Toolbar**

Comment: "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"  in menifest file and try..

Comment: @NaveenKumarM Change your `AppBarLayout` theme to this `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` try and check.

Comment: No its not working. May be Bottombar is giving trouble I think.
Refenece : http://androidgifts.com/build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation/

Comment: @NaveenKumarM Try removing bottom bar integration for cross check you will come to know if it's causing problem. otherwise you have something mismatch with themes.

Comment: Yes, the above issue belong to Bottmbar library.
I resolved it
https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/issues/61

Answer (score 3):

try to make change as below, and set your layout accordingly..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".home.HomeActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Style attributes are as below,

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Manifest Application tag as below,

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".home.HomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: please mention your changes.

Comment: @NaveenKumarM: please post your complete xml with all style, @style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay and app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" ..

Comment: @NaveenKumarM: i have just tried by removing your both style for testing purpose only and update my answer it's working well on my side. let me know it's working or not on your side.

Comment: Tez, Here is the styles:
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

Comment: @NaveenKumarM: i have updated my answer and it's completely working on my side. let me know it's working on your side or not.

Comment: I removed both styles. I copied as it is you mentioned but it's not working.

Comment: @NaveenKumarM: see my complete updated answer now, it's must be working as i even tested on my side also. if still problem exists may be somthing wrong with your status bar space.

Comment: @Tez You should explain whatever changes you are doing in your answer.

Comment: @Tez, Still not working. 
I implemented Bottmbar via this tutorial : http://androidgifts.com/build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation/ 
May be is this cause any problem?

Comment: Yes, the above issue belong to Bottmbar library.
I resolved it
https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/issues/61